# How to wrap an instance of a div inside a box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript, so bear with me if I'm not explaining what I want that well. So basically I have a form for creating activities, so whenever the user fills the fields and hit save it will create an instance of the div containing the information. Now those information are basically just in lines, and I would like to organize them inside a box (div), but I'm not sure how to create it, is it  using JS or HTMl?

Here is a picture of what I have working right now. 
[image]

And here is a view of the code.

```
window.onload = function() {
function addAct(nameact, when, where,desc) {
var buses = document.querySelectorAll(".bus");
var curr = document.createElement("div");
curr.setAttribute("class", "name");
var p0 = document.createElement("p");
p0.setAttribute("class", "nameact");
p0.innerHTML = nameact;
var p1 = document.createElement("p");
p1.setAttribute("class", "whereisit");
p1.innerHTML = when;
var p2 = document.createElement("p");
p2.setAttribute("class", "when");
p2.innerHTML = where;
var p3 = document.createElement("p");
p3.setAttribute("class", "describtion");
p3.innerHTML = desc;
curr.appendChild(p0);
curr.appendChild(p1);
curr.appendChild(p2);
curr.appendChild(p3);
if (buses.length) {
  buses[buses.length -1].insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", curr.outerHTML)
} else {
  document.forms[1].insertAdjacentHTML("afterEnd", curr.outerHTML)
}
}

var obj = {nameact: "", when: "", where: "",desc:""};

document.forms[1].onchange = function(e) {
 obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
 }

document.forms[1].onsubmit = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
addAct(obj.nameact, obj.when, obj.where, obj.desc)
}
}

<section id="cd-placeholder-2" class="cd-section cd-container">
        <h2>Activities</h2>     
        <div id="Slider" class="slide-up">
            <div>
                <div class="contents" >


        <form class="form2">

                      <div class="col-3">
                        <label>
                          Activity Name
                          <input placeholder="What is your activity?" tabindex="3" name="nameact" />
                        </label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-3">
                        <label>
                          Where?
                          <input placeholder="Where is it going to be?" tabindex="4" name="when" />
                        </label>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-3">
                        <label>
                          When?
                          <input type="date" placeholder="mm\dd\yy" tabindex="4" name="where"/>
                        </label>
                      </div>

                      <div>
                        <label>
                          Care to share more?
                          <textarea placeholder="describtion of your activity" class="text" name="desc"></textarea>
                        </label>
                      </div>

                        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="cd-btn" id="col-submit" style="position:relative;float:right;overflow:hidden;margin:10px;margin-top:30px;">Add Activity</button>


        </form>

                    <div id="name"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

Any feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: What you really need is CSS.

Comment: Could you tell me how can I approach it?

Comment: @MaryamAl-Mansour you can check my answer. If it doesn't work leave me a comment. If it works please 'accept as answer'

Comment: @MaryamAl-Mansour can you also add your form HTML to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need HTML+CSS+JS

HTML :

```
<div id="name"></div>
```

CSS

```
.row{
    background-color: red;
    border: 5px solid #333;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nameact{
    background-color:red;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.whereisit{
    background-color:green;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.when{
    background-color:blue;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
 }
.describtion{
    background-color:brown;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JS

```
var obj = {nameact: "", when: "", where: "",desc:""};

document.forms[1].onchange = function(e) {
 obj[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
 }

document.forms[1].onsubmit = function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
addAct(obj.nameact, obj.when, obj.where, obj.desc)
}

function addAct(nameact, when, where,desc) {
var myhtml = '<div class="row"><div class="nameact">'+nameact+'</div><div class="whereisit">'+where+'</div><div class="when">'+when+'</div><div class="describtion">'+describtion+'</div></div>';

document.getElementById('name').innerHTML += myhtml;

}
```

You will need to update CSS code, based on your needs

Comment: Thank you, It worked, but it still doesn't create a box or div over the information.

Comment: @MaryamAl-Mansour It actually creates the box but you were not able to see it. Now I updated css code, You should also update yours. I think then you will realize what you must do. Remaining part is all about CSS and I guess you should study on it.

Comment: @MaryamAl-Mansour kyle's answer above is a good example for what you can do with CSS.

Comment: I mean, I understand CSS, but whenever I try to create a border on the whole thing which is in this case div class= row, it just it doesn't work with me. right now I know how to make each div has a background, but isn't the row div is encompassing all of them? that's what I'm trying to accomplish. I tried Kyle's code, but it didn't work.

Comment: @MaryamAl-Mansour good to hear  can you mark my answer as 'Accept as Answer' , if it solved the problem? Thanks

Comment: Is it by doing the increase button, because I did that multiple times.

Comment: @MaryamAl-Mansour there must be a tick button next to my answer, explained here http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks, did that!

Answer (score 0):

If you need any help understanding this, please let me know. I've written a few css styles, and the html markup that they will be applied to. Make your javascript produce this markup, and do some reading about CSS to extrapolate this into a complete module.

```
<style>
    .activity {
        width: 645px;
        height: 160px;
        border: 2px solid #0000ff;
    }

    .activity > div {
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .activity .top {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        width: 174px;
        height: 30;
        border-right: 1px solid #0000ff;
    }

    .activity .top.end {
        width: 175px;
        border-right: none;
    }

    .activity .bottom {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        width: 605px;
        height: 50;
        border-top: 1px solid #0000ff;
    }

    .activity .title {
        display: block;
    }


</style>


<div class="activity">
    <div class="top">
        <span class="title">ACTIVITY NAME</span>
        <span>Skydiving</span>
    </div>

    <div class="top">
        <span class="title">WHERE?</span>
        <span>Dubai Palm Island</span>
    </div>

    <div class="top end">
        <span class="title">2017-06-22</span>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
        <span>CARE TO SHARE MORE?</span>
        <span class="title">It will be a fun trip!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this gets you headed in the right direction!